# Facing Error when i go install flutter ARcore plugin in my project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, arcore

i want to creat  flutter a project about AR.
but when i am going to install the ARcore plugin for flutter , i am facing this problem.
which is [this is error in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuKK2.png)

## this is error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':arcore_flutter_plugin' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps to solve your problem.

1. If working on Android Studio expand External Libraries tab.
2. Find your arcore_flutter_plugin.
3. Go to android folder of that plugin.
4. Open build.gradle file and change the kotlin version to 1.5.20